# Exporting blank pdf using ghost script

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

I am using the ghost script writer to produce PDF's...and it works but it produces blank ones.
I have searched a lot in this, but i didn't find anything that could help me.

I'm using windows 7 64-bits and I have found this issue on Windows 7 32-bit.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Please confirm what is going wrong - is it printing the desired document and a blank page?